# print n lines of a "command's --help" on stdout

Tags: bash, shell, stdout

This is just as a curiosity that I haven't managed to solve (trying sed, awk, tail, head, etc.).

This works:

```
$ ls --help | head -n 2
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
```

Why with other commands it does not work?

```
$ tree --help | head -n 2 
Prints the whole --help! not just the first 2 lines!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tree` (and some other commands) print their help to stderr, not stdout. You could simply redirect both by using `|&` instead of `|`:

```
tree --help |& head -n2
```

Comment: Or use `tree --help 2>&1 | head -n2` (or similar) for bash versions older than 4 (which is where `|&` was added I believe).